# Email Subject - Is it correct to write "Regarding xyz......." in the email subject?

Tags: grammaticality, formality, email

Whenever I write an email to someone...I usually write "Regarding" in the subject. Is it a formal way to write email subject.

Examples:-

```
"Regarding application for the post of product manager"
"Regarding scanned copy of my ID card"
```

Is there any better way for writing email subject lines?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/regarding-re-what-is-the-correct-usage-in-an-email-subject-line

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you put in the **Subject line** of an email should contain a **brief summary** and be relevant to whatever is in the **body**.

In your examples

> **Regarding** application for the post of product manager
>   **Regarding** scanned copy of my ID card

one would expect the Subject lines to be instead

> Application for the post of product manager
>   Scanned copy of my ID card

The Subject line can be made even more specific by adding ***your name** followed by a '-'(hyphen) and the rest of your planned Subject line

> **John Doe** - Application for the post of product manager
>   **Jane Doe** - Scanned copy of my ID card

int his way it is easier for the recipient to search for you without needing to remember you remain address.

Most email programs will **prepend RE:** meaning **in regards to** or **in response to** when replying to an email. The response Subject line would then look like this

> RE: Application for the post of product manager
>   RE: Scanned copy of my ID card

Using **regarding** in your example is **not necessary** since the email is **obviously** regarding whatever is also mentioned in the Subject line.  It is usually better to be less wordy as with a **headline**